# PWA for IMAP (Mail Client)

Tags: javascript, imap, progressive-web-apps

I would like to write a progressive-web-app for reading mails stored on a IMAP server.

But AFAIK Javascript in the browser jail can't connect to an IMAP server.

I see two solutions:

1. drop the dream to create a progressive-web-app (which works without installing something). For example use electron
2. Write an https service which forwards the requests to IMAP. But this means someone needs to run a service. All passwords go through this service. A direct connection between client and IMAP-server is preferred.

I guess there is a third or maybe fourth solution.

Wishes:

- No installation on the client should be required (mobile and PC). That would be great

How could this be solved?

Comment: I'd say writing an HTTP service is the way to go and plugging it into your existing API for your PWA. Use an existing authentication scheme like O-AUTH for users to login to their mail server of choice. There really isn't another way around it. Don't give up on the PWA, this will be fine and actually isn't very hard to do.

Comment: @Willman.Codes That will not work in the browser sandbox, will only work in a node environment.

Comment: Passwords generally need to go through that service, but not necessarily. [Gmail and RFC 7628](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7628) both avoid that.

Comment: @arnt OAuth for smtp and imap. Cool. That was new for me. Thank.you for this hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. As you already stated, you can't directly connect from the browser. You'll need a service for that, could be a simple "proxy" using serverless function maybe?

Comment: If you have a PWA you probably already have an API setup of some kind (rest, graphql or what have you). I'd say it is best to just integrate it into your existing API in a way that makes sense for your app, since you can translate the data however you want. So rather than just a proxy, you get a clean interface that makes sense in the context of your app and you can go on to support other standards in the future and have the same API to use on the client so it all works a little more seamlessly.

Comment: Probably? Why? If you have a PWA that acts as an email client, you don't need any API. You can serve the app from a static server. You just need a way to connect to a mail server.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. He asked a question, my answer is it can't be done. If you disagree, prove me wrong with your own answer. I suggested using a simple serverless function as an unintrusive proxy, which is the closest thing possible to what he wants.